# citrix thin client performance issue

Tags: performance, client, thin, citrix, xenapp

I'm having following problem:

We, in our company, are working in a mixed environment. Thin clients (HP-T520) and laptops. Our users connect to a citrix server to go onto the internet. We use a web application for our main business (which we navigate to trough citrix).

We notice a remarkable performance issue on the thin clients. The laptops are not facing this performance issue.

Someone can help me finding the root cause of this issue? I presume there will be some local resources used on the portable which are not available on the thin client, but I do not have a clue where to look or log this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the same operating systems installed on the thin clients and laptops?
Which versions of Citrix Receiver is installed on the thin clients and laptops?
Are the laptops using a wireless connection or the same wired connection as the thin clients? The factors can lead you to the root cause.

Answer (score -1):

We managed to resolve the issue. The Thin Clients had Citrix version 4.1 installed. This version doesn't have gfx render. We upgraded to version 4.5, this resolved the issue since it uses hardware acceleration.